# How to set public permissions for files but not directories/folders in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket and I want its content to be public but not the folders, essentially allow access to any image or document in any folder or subfolder but deny access if I try to access the folder.

I currently use this Bucket Policy which gets the work pretty close:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1666356335738",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessContent",
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy:

1. I can access the content
2. I get a `403` if I try to access a folder without trailing slash
3. I get a `200` and the browser downloads an empty file named `download` if I try to access a folder using a trailing slash

How can I modify and configure my bucket so that also in the third case (using trailing slash) I get a `403` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders **do not actually exist** in Amazon S3.

If you upload a file to a location (eg `invoices/january.txt`), then the `invoices` folder **will magically 'appear'**. However, it doesn't actually exist. If the object was then deleted, the `invoices` folder will 'disappear' because it never actually existed.

If you click the **Create folder** button in the Amazon S3 management console, then it **creates a zero-length object with the name of the folder**. This causes the folder to 'appear' even if there are no objects in that path (because the zero-length object is 'in' the path). This is probably what is happening with your Case #3.

You can resolve it by **deleting the zero-length object with the name of the folder** (which includes the trailing slash). This will *not* delete any objects inside the folder (because folders do not actually exist).

You can use: `aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/folder-name/`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please tell me how should I delete the **zero-length object with the name of the folder** ? Can I do this through the Amazon S3 management console or does it has to be done through my terminal ?

Comment: I accepted you answer as you provided me with very insightful information that helped me move forward. I would still be interested in a solution that would allow me to "delete" a folder created through the Amazone S3 management console without deleting its content.

Comment: You can simply delete the zero-length object. You can use the AWS CLI: `aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/folder-name/` It will _not_ delete the contents of the folder.